# R MySQL to no-default schema

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, rmysql

I am trying to utilize dbWriteTable to write from R to MySQL.  When I connect to MySQL I created an odbc connection so I can just utilize the command:

```
abc <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                       dsn = "mysql_conn")
```

In which I can see all my schemas for the MySQL instance.  This is great when I want to read in data such as:

```
test_query <- dbSendQuery(abc, "SELECT * FROM test_schema.test_file")
test_query <- dbFetch(test_query)
```

The problem I have is when I want to create a new table in one of the schema's how to declare the schema I want to write to in

```
dbWriteTable(abc, value = new_file, name = "new_file", overwrite=T)
```

I imagine I have to define the test_schema in the dbWriteTable portion but haven't been able to get it to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: Try `dbWriteTable(con, c("schema","table"),dataframe)`

Comment: I tried that but I received this error message: Error: length(name) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: Actually this command I get it from [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues/181)

Comment: Once that command appears, I don't see how to get that write to the table.

Comment: Any other thoughts on how to solve this?  Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have.

Comment: What error you are getting? I've worked with `pool` and `DBI` packages to connect with `MySQL` and 1: successfully exported a dataframe to new table 2: `overwrite` the existing table with new dataframe.